# Keras - passing different parameter for different data point onto Lambda Layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I am working on a CNN model in Keras/TF background. At the end of final convolutional layer, I need to pool the output maps from the filters. Instead of using `GlobalAveragePooling` or any other sort of pooling, I had to pool according to time frames which exist along the width of the output map.

So if a sample output from one filter is let's say `n x m`, `n` being time frames and `m` outputs along the features. Here I just need to pool output from frames `n1 to n2` where `n1` and `n2` <= n. So my output slice is `(n2-n1)*m`, on which I will apply pooling. I came across [`Lambda Layer`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) of keras to do this. But I am stuck at a point where `n1` and `n2` will be different for each points. So my question is how can pass a custom argument for each data point onto a `Lambda Layer`? or am I approaching this in a wrong way?

A sample snippet:

```
# for slicing a tensor
def time_based_slicing(x, crop_at):
    dim = x.get_shape()
    len_ = crop_at[1] - crop_at[0]
    return tf.slice(x, [0, crop_at[0], 0, 0], [1, len_, dim[2], dim[3]])

# for output shape
def return_out_shape(input_shape):
    return tuple([input_shape[0], None, input_shape[2], input_shape[3]])

# lambda layer addition
model.add(Lambda(time_based_slicing, output_shape=return_out_shape, arguments={'crop_at': (2, 5)}))
```

The above argument `crop_at` needs to be custom for each data point when fitting in a loop. Any pointers/clues to this will be helpful.

Comment: Why is the timeframe different for each data point? Do you know the timeframes beforehand? You could store the timeframe indices in a text file and pass them as an additional `Input` to your model.

Comment: Each point is a bunch of frames. From t1 to t2, lets say we tagged it for a particular class. And Yes I know these for test data. I will check the additional input part you mentioned.

Comment: @sdcbr The additional `Input` which you are mentioning is an input right. Does it have any weights associated with it? I was searching for `Lambda` layers and was not in them because do they do get tweaked in backprop.

Comment: Yes a second Input layer without weights that goes straight to the Lambda addition layer

Comment: @sdcbr The input layer you had mentioned was right and I completed the slice based on it. If you can write an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you know the indices of the time frames that belong to each datapoint from before, you can store them in a text file and pass them as an additional `Input` to your model:

```
slice_input = Input((2,))
```

And use those in your `time_based_slicing` function.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from Sequential API - it starts to fall apart when you need to use multiple inputs: use Functional API https://keras.io/models/model/

Assuming that your lambda functions are correct:

```
def time_based_slicing(inputs_list):
    x, crop_at = inputs_list
    ... (will probably need to do some work to subset crop_at since it will be a tensor now instead of constants

inp = Input(your_shape)
inp_additional = Inp((2,)
x=YOUR_CNN_LOGIC(inp)
out = Lambda(time_based_slicing)([x,inp_additional])
```

Comment: Yes, I did switch from sequential api to functional api looking at the mess. I think what i need is just input layer since i dont need to multiply it with weights. I will update if i complete it successfully.