# Keras/Tensorflow: Combined Loss function for single output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I have only one output for my model, but I would like to combine two different loss functions:

```
def get_model():
    # create the model here
    model = Model(inputs=image, outputs=output)

    alpha = 0.2
    model.compile(loss=[mse, gse],
                      loss_weights=[1-alpha, alpha]
                      , ...)
```

but it complains that I need to have two outputs because I defined two losses:

```
ValueError: When passing a list as loss, it should have one entry per model outputs. 
The model has 1 outputs, but you passed loss=[<function mse at 0x0000024D7E1FB378>, <function gse at 0x0000024D7E1FB510>]
```

Can I possibly write my final loss function without having to create another loss function (because that would restrict me from changing the alpha outside the loss function)?

**How do I do something like `(1-alpha)*mse + alpha*gse`?**

---

Update:

Both my loss functions are equivalent to the function signature of any builtin keras loss function, takes in `y_true` and `y_pred` and gives a tensor back for loss (which can be reduced to a scalar using `K.mean()`), but I believe, how these loss functions are defined shouldn't affect the answer as long as they return valid losses.

```
def gse(y_true, y_pred):
    # some tensor operation on y_pred and y_true
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

Comment: could you add your gse function?

Comment: here a simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62861773/can-we-use-multiple-loss-functions-in-same-layer/62862033#62862033

Comment: Is it necessary to multiply a value less than 1 to each of the individual losses or can one even multiply a value more than 1. Like for example 5*mse + 3*gse. In this case what can be the pros and cons of the loss formulation? I wanted to know why one needs to have l_1 + l_2 + ... + l_n = 1? Where l_i's are the constants added to each of the loss functions....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Specify a custom function for the loss:

```
model = Model(inputs=image, outputs=output)

alpha = 0.2
model.compile(
    loss=lambda y_true, y_pred: (1 - alpha) * mse(y_true, y_pred) + alpha * gse(y_true, y_pred),
    ...)
```

Or if you don't want an ugly lambda make it into an actual function:

```
def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return (1 - alpha) * mse(y_true, y_pred) + alpha * gse(y_true, y_pred)

model = Model(inputs=image, outputs=output)

alpha = 0.2
model.compile(loss=my_loss, ...)
```

*EDIT:*

If your `alpha` is not some global constant, you can have a "loss function factory":

```
def make_my_loss(alpha):
    def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return (1 - alpha) * mse(y_true, y_pred) + alpha * gse(y_true, y_pred)
    return my_loss

model = Model(inputs=image, outputs=output)

alpha = 0.2
my_loss = make_my_loss(alpha)
model.compile(loss=my_loss, ...)
```

Comment: usually when I define custom losses, I will have to pass that in the dict when loading the model, but if I pass a lambda, do I need to pass that somehow or will it work just right?

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Not sure what dict you are referring to... Are you talking about the model definition part, or checkpointing, or something else? Where exactly would you usually need to put the custom loss you define?

Comment: if I save a model with custom losses I will have to tell keras what they are when loading the same. So `import gse from somewhere` and then `load_model(model_file, custom_objects={'gse':gse}`. `custom_objects` dict...!

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Ahh I see, sorry I was not aware of this API of Keras models. I have only saved and restored models using TensorFlow tooling, I'm not sure how Keras mechanism works, so I wouldn't know for sure, but it does seem that all non-standard functions (including lambdas, I'd suspect) have to be passed as `custom_objects` or provided by a `CustomObjectScope`...

Comment: Yep, it can't seem to get the anonymous function as expected. Throws `ValueError: Unknown loss function:<lambda>` error when loading the model after saving.

Comment: how do I put `alpha` inside of the loss function since I can't pass `alpha` as a parameter. For one, my model is inside of another function so local variable `alpha` would not be accessible outside. I can choose to make it global, but then when I load the loss from outside, it would have `alpha` as None :(

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran I've extended the example with a "factory function" that would create the necessary loss function with the passed `alpha` value. I think it should be still saveable as a custom object.

Comment: factory definitely helps, and if I pass in the same alpha when loading, it would work perfectly. Only problem I see is remembering this alpha -> which means, this has to be saved outside `model.json` and pass this alpha along with it whenever giving the model architecture `model.json` and weights `weights.h5`, so as to make it possible for others to load. The right way would be saving this as a variable inside of keras model, like how keras does for `loss_weights`. Until someone or I raises a PR, this can be used :)

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran I see what you mean. I thought you could save your custom objects with the models, but you have to specify them on load. One possible workaround (even if not ideal) would be to save additional information for example to a [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) file. Unfortunately pickle cannot handle locally defined functions (e.g. the function returned by the factory), but you could save the alpha value and other stuff...

Answer (score 0):

`loss` function should be one function.You are giving your model a list of two functions

try:

```
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)

model.compile(loss= (mse(y_true, y_pred)*(1-alpha) + gse(y_true, y_pred)*alpha),
              , ...)
```

Comment: You mean to say `loss=(mse*(1-alpha) + gse*alpha)`?

Comment: I don't think we can do arithmetic on functions in Python, but anyway I tried but got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'`

Comment: what is gse function?

Comment: it is exactly like how you have defined `mse` in your answer. the problem is it doesn't know what `function * float` means, so it just complains `unsupported operand`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, define your own custom loss function and pass that to the `loss` argument upon compiling:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return (1-alpha) * K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred)) + alpha * gse
```

(Not sure what you mean with `gse`). It can be helpful to have a look at how the vanilla losses are implemented in Keras: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py

Comment: `gse` is a function just like `mse` (Updated the question), so we would have to pass in `y_true` and `y_pred` to it when calling, we can't do `alpha * gse`.

Comment: Because `gse` is a function. Try writing it out as a single custom loss function as above.

Comment: sorry if I misunderstood you, but `alpha` would be a scalar like `0.1` or `0.2` and keras wouldn't know how to multiply a function `gse` or `mse` with a scalar `alpha` and would throw `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that gse is a function. If you write it out as a single custom loss function like above, with `gse` replace by it's definition, do you still get the error?

Comment: gotcha, you suggest to create another loss function incorporating both the losses inside. But alpha can't be changed when I define the model :(

Comment: Don't you know alpha beforehand?

Comment: nope! that's the problem!!! I will have to vary it. But for now looks like I should go with assigning the `alpha` inside beforehand

Comment: That's not clear from your question. If you want to vary it during training, you could try providing an `alpha` tensor as an additional `Input` to your model and use it inside your loss function. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557383/keras-passing-different-parameter-for-different-data-point-onto-lambda-layer/51688043#51688043) question

Answer (score 0):

Not that this answer particularly addresses the original question, I thought of writing it because the same error occurs when trying to load a keras model that has a custom loss using `keras.models.load_model`, and it's not been properly answered anywhere. Specifically, following the VAE example code in [keras github repository](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py), this error occurs when loading the VAE model after been saved with `model.save`.

The solution is to save only the weights using `vae.save_weights('file.h5')` instead of saving the full model. However, you would have to build and compile the model again before loading the weights using `vae.load_weights('file.h5')`.

Following is an example implementation.

```
class VAE():
    def build_model(self): # latent_dim and intermediate_dim can be passed as arguments
        def sampling(args):
            """Reparameterization trick by sampling from an isotropic unit Gaussian.
            # Arguments
                args (tensor): mean and log of variance of Q(z|X)
            # Returns
                z (tensor): sampled latent vector
            """

            z_mean, z_log_var = args
            batch = K.shape(z_mean)[0]
            dim = K.int_shape(z_mean)[1]
            # by default, random_normal has mean = 0 and std = 1.0
            epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
            return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

        # original_dim = self.no_features
        # intermediate_dim = 256
        latent_dim = 8
        inputs = Input(shape=(self.no_features,))
        x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(inputs)
        x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
        z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_mean')(x)
        z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name='z_log_var')(x)
        # use reparameterization trick to push the sampling out as input
        # note that "output_shape" isn't necessary with the TensorFlow backend
        z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,), name='z')([z_mean, z_log_var])
        # instantiate encoder model
        encoder = Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name='encoder')


        # build decoder model
        latent_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
        x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
        x = Dense(48, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
        outputs = Dense(self.no_features, activation='linear')(x)

        # instantiate decoder model
        decoder = Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')

        # instantiate VAE model
        outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
        VAE = Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')
        reconstruction_loss = mse(inputs, outputs)
        reconstruction_loss *= self.no_features
        kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
        kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
        kl_loss *= -0.5
        vae_loss = K.mean(reconstruction_loss + kl_loss)
        VAE.add_loss(vae_loss)
        VAE.compile(optimizer='adam')
        return VAE
```

Now,

```
vae_cls = VAE()
vae = vae_cls.build_model()
# vae.fit()
vae.save_weights('file.h5')
```

Load model and predict (if in a different script, you need to import the `VAE` class),

```
vae_cls = VAE()
vae = vae_cls.build_model()
vae.load_weights('file.h5')
# vae.predict()
```

Finally, **The Difference**: [[ref](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/)]

Keras `model.save` saves,

1. Model weights
2. Model architecture
3. Model compilation details (loss function(s) and metrics)
4. Model optimizer and regularizer states

Keras `model.save_weights` saves only the model weights. Keras `model.to_json()` saves the model architecture.

Hope this helps someone experimenting with variational autoencoders.

Answer (score 0):

Combine `MAE` and `RMSE` together:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def loss_fn_mae_rmse(y_true, y_pred, alpha=0.8):
    mae = keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    mse = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    return alpha * mae(y_true, y_pred) + (1 - alpha) * tf.sqrt(mse(y_true, y_pred))

model = keras.Model(inputs=..., outputs=...)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss_fn_mae_rmse, metrics=['mae'])
```

At the same time, if you want to load this model after training and saved to disk:

```
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/model.h5', custom_objects={'loss_fn_mae_rmse': loss_fn_mae_rmse})
```